# Grunt Usemin: How to define targets?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I was wondering how i can use "targets" with grunt usemin. 
e.g. to run sth. like: **grunt usemin:app**

This is what I tried (Error: Warning: Object # has no method 'indexOf' Use --force to continue.) – same for useminPrepare

```
   usemin: {
        app : {
            html: ['<%= config.app.dist %>/app/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.app.dist %>/app/css/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= config.app.dist %>/app']
            }
        },
        site: {
            html: ['<%= config.site.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
            css: ['<%= config.site.dist %>/css/{,*/}*.css'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= config.site.dist %>']
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score -1):

In grunt usemin the targets are defined in the html page not in gruntfile.

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/underscore/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/backbone/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/backbone.localStorage/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Here `scripts/vendor.js` is the target.

Source : https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#the-useminprepare-task

Comment: Thanks. But that's nothing i was looking for. I need to 'build' to separate projects form one source (1. A webpage 2. A mobile app)